# sqlite mistake in otherwise working script

Tags: sql, sqlite

Why do I get the following error message in sqlite3

```
Error: near line 99: near ".": syntax error

SELECT cast.cast_id, cast.cast_name, AVG(movies.score)
FROM movies
INNER JOIN cast ON cast.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE movies.score >= 40
GROUP BY cast.cast_name
HAVING COUNT(movies.id) >= 2
ORDER BY AVG(movies.score) DESC, cast.cast_name DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Line 99 is the first line (the SELECT line)

Answer (score 4):

`cast` is a reserved word in SQLite.  That makes it a really bad choice for a table or column name.  The list of reserved words is in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

If you cannot change the table name, use explicit aliases:

```
SELECT c.cast_id, c.cast_name, AVG(m.score)
FROM movies m INNER JOIN
     "cast" c
     ON c.movie_id = m.id
WHERE m.score >= 40
GROUP BY c.cast_id, c.cast_name
HAVING COUNT(m.id) >= 2
ORDER BY AVG(m.score) DESC, c.cast_name DESC;
```

Notes:

- The table name is surrounded by escape characters (backticks and square braces also work).
- The `GROUP BY` has all unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.
- Aliases are abbreviations for the table names.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  That fixed the problem.  I still have so much to learn about SQL.